# Count Down Timer in multiple acitivites

Tags: android

I have a button  named next and a textview in my first activity ,which represent the time remaining (took count down timer and showing the time left in textview),so when i click on next button another acivity(SecondActivity) will be launched where i have another textview,here also am showing the time left,The problem here is when i am going from first activity to second  acitivity the timer is again starting from 20 seconds and counting down,i dont want that to happen what i want is ,the remaining time should be continued in second activity's textview.How can i do it,Any help will be appreciated

Comment: If you upload a sample of the code you have so far it should be easier to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can either make your `Timer` more global (in `Application`) or pass the current value to the next Activity as an `Intent` extra (probably better).

Answer (score 0):

1. you can use application class to track the remaining time.
2. Pass remaining time to another activity in intent.
3. store the remaining time in a global static variable (not recommended)

Comment: Your answer is pretty terse, can you elaborate on the options, why is three not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Pass data to new activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_TIME", time);
startActivity(intent)
```